# Abort Android in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

i am looking for a way to abort an ongoing in-app billing request. my understanding was that when i get the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED notification, but i do not respond to it with CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS, the google server continues to send the message. when it never gets the expected response, i thought it might abort the purchase with "took too long to deliver" or so. this does, however, not happen. i get the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED notification just once and the purchase goes through as if i had confirmed the message. do i get something wrong here or is that a problem with the checkout process itself?

thanks
simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not you do a CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS to a order, it doesn't affect the order status. The reason why you have to confirm an order is to prevent google from sending back IN_APP_NOTIFY message in the future again in case the device's connection drops. I believe once the user is taken to the android market buy page, and click the button, there is nothing you can do in code to abort the process.